# Resource modifications not recompiling

Tags: asp.net, .net-3.5, resources, embedded-resource

I am in the process of attempting to make some small changes to the TeamLab application that is available [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/teamlab/files/Teamlab%20v6.0/), specifically version teamlab.v6.0.31115

All I am attempting to do is modify a `Resource.resx` file located in the App_GlobalResources folder but unfortunately to no avail. Inside of the application the resources that I am attempting to modify are accessed as such.

```
string ResourceValue = Resources.Resource.ResourceName;
```

I have simply navigated into the resx file through visual studio, made the required changes and attempted to run the program. However none of the changes are appearing while I debug and the old resource values are still appearing.

I have attempted to change the resource files build action which is currently set to content to both resource and embedded resource and neither helped. I realize this is a very broad question but I am somewhat out of ideas. Could anyone possibly provide any guidance as to what I might be doing incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that despite having a Resource file for the project TeamLab uses its database for resource text.

For anyone interested the majority of the resource text is in a table called res_data